# Replacing hard-drives and installing fresh OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bios

Earlier I had a HDD with ubuntu and windows on dual-boot. I replaced it with SSD and tried to install ubuntu, which gave me errors due to grub and said the OS would be unbootable.

Then to fix this I used boot-repair, which generated this report(http://paste2.org/8z0GLGCC) with an error in the end. 
[image]

What do I know?

Comment: You replaced HDD with SSD and wanted to repair what? If the SSD was empty, there is nothing to repair! Make sure you have the correct Ubuntu ISO file (probably amd64) and make sure your SSD has a GPT partition scheme. GRUB is ussually installed at the beginning of the (first) disk.

Comment: @ipselute thanks for the reply! How can I make sure the SD has GPT partition scheme?

Comment: Your drive has GPT partition scheme. We can see that in boot-info summary. Install looks clean. the error at the end is not relevant.Can you boot after the repair?

Comment: But my os installation was unsuccessful itself.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Did you make sure to first format the SSD, then install? I don't see an issue here. Also, you could buy an HDD cloner adapter and clone the data off your HDD and put it on your SSD.